# Trouble linking libboost libraries to compile sslsniff on RHEL

Tags: boost, linker, boost-thread, rhel, rhel5

Trying to build `sslsniff` on a RHEL 5.2 system here. When compiling `sslsniff` on RHEL I hit the same errors when using `libboost` packages (from repositories like rpmforge) and compiling `libboost` from source (which appeared to be successful.) I tried this on a fresh system as well (no previous/failed/garbage installs of `libboost` etc.)

```
# make
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT SSLConnectionManager.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/SSLConnectionManager.Tpo -c -o SSLConnectionManager.o SSLConnectionManager.cpp
mv -f .deps/SSLConnectionManager.Tpo .deps/SSLConnectionManager.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT FirefoxUpdater.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/FirefoxUpdater.Tpo -c -o FirefoxUpdater.o FirefoxUpdater.cpp
mv -f .deps/FirefoxUpdater.Tpo .deps/FirefoxUpdater.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT Logger.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Logger.Tpo -c -o Logger.o Logger.cpp
mv -f .deps/Logger.Tpo .deps/Logger.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT SessionCache.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/SessionCache.Tpo -c -o SessionCache.o SessionCache.cpp
mv -f .deps/SessionCache.Tpo .deps/SessionCache.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT SSLBridge.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/SSLBridge.Tpo -c -o SSLBridge.o SSLBridge.cpp
mv -f .deps/SSLBridge.Tpo .deps/SSLBridge.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT HTTPSBridge.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/HTTPSBridge.Tpo -c -o HTTPSBridge.o HTTPSBridge.cpp
mv -f .deps/HTTPSBridge.Tpo .deps/HTTPSBridge.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT sslsniff.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/sslsniff.Tpo -c -o sslsniff.o sslsniff.cpp
mv -f .deps/sslsniff.Tpo .deps/sslsniff.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT FingerprintManager.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/FingerprintManager.Tpo -c -o FingerprintManager.o FingerprintManager.cpp
mv -f .deps/FingerprintManager.Tpo .deps/FingerprintManager.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT AuthorityCertificateManager.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/AuthorityCertificateManager.Tpo -c -o AuthorityCertificateManager.o `test -f 'certificate/AuthorityCertificateManager.cpp' || echo './'`certificate/AuthorityCertificateManager.cpp
mv -f .deps/AuthorityCertificateManager.Tpo .deps/AuthorityCertificateManager.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT TargetedCertificateManager.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/TargetedCertificateManager.Tpo -c -o TargetedCertificateManager.o `test -f 'certificate/TargetedCertificateManager.cpp' || echo './'`certificate/TargetedCertificateManager.cpp
mv -f .deps/TargetedCertificateManager.Tpo .deps/TargetedCertificateManager.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT CertificateManager.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/CertificateManager.Tpo -c -o CertificateManager.o `test -f 'certificate/CertificateManager.cpp' || echo './'`certificate/CertificateManager.cpp
mv -f .deps/CertificateManager.Tpo .deps/CertificateManager.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT HttpBridge.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/HttpBridge.Tpo -c -o HttpBridge.o `test -f 'http/HttpBridge.cpp' || echo './'`http/HttpBridge.cpp
mv -f .deps/HttpBridge.Tpo .deps/HttpBridge.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT HttpConnectionManager.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/HttpConnectionManager.Tpo -c -o HttpConnectionManager.o `test -f 'http/HttpConnectionManager.cpp' || echo './'`http/HttpConnectionManager.cpp
mv -f .deps/HttpConnectionManager.Tpo .deps/HttpConnectionManager.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT HttpHeaders.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/HttpHeaders.Tpo -c -o HttpHeaders.o `test -f 'http/HttpHeaders.cpp' || echo './'`http/HttpHeaders.cpp
mv -f .deps/HttpHeaders.Tpo .deps/HttpHeaders.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT UpdateManager.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/UpdateManager.Tpo -c -o UpdateManager.o UpdateManager.cpp
mv -f .deps/UpdateManager.Tpo .deps/UpdateManager.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT OCSPDenier.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/OCSPDenier.Tpo -c -o OCSPDenier.o `test -f 'http/OCSPDenier.cpp' || echo './'`http/OCSPDenier.cpp
mv -f .deps/OCSPDenier.Tpo .deps/OCSPDenier.Po
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"sslsniff\" -DVERSION=\"0.6\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -I.    -ggdb -g -O2 -MT FirefoxAddonUpdater.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/FirefoxAddonUpdater.Tpo -c -o FirefoxAddonUpdater.o FirefoxAddonUpdater.cpp
mv -f .deps/FirefoxAddonUpdater.Tpo .deps/FirefoxAddonUpdater.Po
g++ -ggdb -g -O2 -lssl -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lboost_thread -llog4cpp  -o sslsniff SSLConnectionManager.o FirefoxUpdater.o Logger.o SessionCache.o SSLBridge.o HTTPSBridge.o sslsniff.o FingerprintManager.o AuthorityCertificateManager.o TargetedCertificateManager.o CertificateManager.o HttpBridge.o HttpConnectionManager.o HttpHeaders.o UpdateManager.o OCSPDenier.o FirefoxAddonUpdater.o  
SSLConnectionManager.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:208: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:209: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
```

There's more, but I guess there's a post length limit..

Most of them appear related to `boost::system` so I added `-lboost_system` to the linker command and got farther:

```
# g++ -ggdb -g -O2 -lssl -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lboost_thread -llog4cpp  -o sslsniff SSLConnectionManager.o FirefoxUpdater.o Logger.o SessionCache.o SSLBridge.o HTTPSBridge.o sslsniff.o FingerprintManager.o AuthorityCertificateManager.o TargetedCertificateManager.o CertificateManager.o HttpBridge.o HttpConnectionManager.o HttpHeaders.o UpdateManager.o OCSPDenier.o FirefoxAddonUpdater.o -lboost_system
SSLConnectionManager.o: In function `thread<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf3<void, SSLConnectionManager, boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>, bool>, boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<SSLConnectionManager*>, boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > >, boost::_bi::value<boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, boost::_bi::value<bool> > > >':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:191: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread()'
SSLConnectionManager.o: In function `~thread_data':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:40: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:40: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:40: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:40: undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
```

Now the errors are related to `boost::detail` and `boost::filesystem::detail`.

I've tried using boost 1.35 and 1.42 (latest).

On my own Ubuntu system, I installed the libraries from Ubuntu repositories and I was able to compile+link sslsniff just fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the system had boost1.33 installed already. `yum erase boost` took care of that:

```
---> Package boost.i386 0:1.33.1-10.el5 set to be erased
---> Package boost.x86_64 0:1.33.1-10.el5 set to be erased
---> Package boost-devel.i386 0:1.33.1-10.el5 set to be erased
---> Package boost-devel.x86_64 0:1.33.1-10.el5 set to be erased
```

Went to rebuild and made sure it was using 1.35.. some were under non-standard names (because of the existing 1.33 possibly?) so I added links..

```
# make
g++ -ggdb -g -O2 -lssl -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lboost_thread -llog4cpp  -o sslsniff SSLConnectionManager.o FirefoxUpdater.o Logger.o SessionCache.o SSLBridge.o HTTPSBridge.o sslsniff.o FingerprintManager.o AuthorityCertificateManager.o TargetedCertificateManager.o CertificateManager.o HttpBridge.o HttpConnectionManager.o HttpHeaders.o UpdateManager.o OCSPDenier.o FirefoxAddonUpdater.o  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sslsniff] Error 1
# cd /usr/lib
# ln -s libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt-1_35.so libboost_filesystem.so
# ln -s libboost_thread-gcc41-mt-1_35.so libboost_thread.so
# cd ~/sslsniff-0.6
# make
g++ -ggdb -g -O2 -lssl -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lboost_thread -llog4cpp  -o sslsniff SSLConnectionManager.o FirefoxUpdater.o Logger.o SessionCache.o SSLBridge.o HTTPSBridge.o sslsniff.o FingerprintManager.o AuthorityCertificateManager.o TargetedCertificateManager.o CertificateManager.o HttpBridge.o HttpConnectionManager.o HttpHeaders.o UpdateManager.o OCSPDenier.o FirefoxAddonUpdater.o 
#
```

But when I try to run it, I get a (non-boost!) library loading error:

```
# ./sslsniff 
./sslsniff: error while loading shared libraries: liblog4cpp.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I installed `liblog4cpp` I/it didn't run `ldconfig` afterwards to update the ld library cache. Did it myself and it worked:

```
# ldconfig
# ./sslsniff 
Usage: ./sslsniff [options]

Modes:
-a  Authority mode.  Specify a certificate that will act as a CA.
-t  Targeted mode.  Specify a directory full of certificates to target.

Required Options:
-c <file|directory> File containing CA cert/key (authority mode) or 
            directory containing a collection of certs/keys
            (targeted mode)
-s <port>       Port to listen on for SSL interception.
-w <file>       File to log to

Optional Options:
-u <updateLocation> Loction of any Firefox XML update files.
-m <certificateChain>   Location of any intermediary certificates.
-h <port>       Port to listen on for HTTP interception (required for
            fingerprinting).
-f <ff,ie,safari,opera> Only intercept requests from the specified browser(s).
-d          Deny OCSP requests for our certificates.
-p          Only log HTTP POSTs
-e <url>        Intercept Mozilla Addon Updates
-j <sha256>     The sha256sum value of the addon to inject
```